# How can I get a gridview to be populated and display in an asp.net webform application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been trying unsuccessfully for about 20 hours now trying to get a gridview to populate/display with data from a dataset that receives its data from a method in the business access layer of an asp.net application.
I have the following for the "front-end"

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/AdminMasterPage.Master"  CodeBehind="employees.aspx.cs" Inherits="FinalProject_ASPNET_H2K.Pages.employees" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceholder3" Runat="Server">
    <br />
    
    <asp:GridView ID="gvEmployees" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" onrowdeleting="gvEmployees_RowDeleting">
         />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeID" HeaderText="Employee ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Designation" HeaderText="Designation" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LevelID" HeaderText="Level" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="username" HeaderText="UserName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="password" HeaderText="Password" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
        </Columns>
        
    </asp:GridView>
 
</asp:Content>
```

And I have the following for the code behind:

```
BusinessAccessLayer.BALayer objBAL = new BusinessAccessLayer.BALayer();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                try
                {

                    
                    DataSet ds = objBAL.GetEmployees();
                    if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("no data received");
                    }
                    else {
                       
                    
                     gvEmployees.DataSource = objBAL.GetEmployees();
                        gvEmployees.DataBind();

                        
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

Can anyone please point out to me what exactly I am doing wrong? I have taken my time to research and try different solutions on my part, however, nothing seems to be working.

(This is not for school/work. Also, please don't get upset if I somehow wrote the question wrong, some people on this site seem to get mad about that).

I've tried running this without the master page as well, when that happens and I look in devtools on chrome there is no gridview being picked up.

Comment: Whats the error? Are you sure your database has the data dn ds has data?

Comment: Well, I feel stupid now, this post should just be deleted. The first comment answered a question. (I always seem to miss things that are 'small'). I think I've been working on this for too many hours straight.

Comment: Sure it ahppens to all of us.  A few suggestions for you. 1) Remove try/catch 2) Only get data once you are doing it twice. 3) Don't use Console to write output put it into  a label or something on your page.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested.  Thank you.